# Why does jQuery.get('/home/user/0/0a.html') fail when using file: rather than http:?

Tags: jquery

In the first two paragraphs a click produces an alert box with the content of the specified file. In the second two there is no alert box.

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../resources/jquery_1-4-2.js"></script>
</head><body>
<p onclick="$.get('/home/user/0/1/2/3/4/4a.html','',function(a){alert(a);});">
Get /home/user/0/1/2/3/4/4a.html</p>
<p onclick="$.get('/home/user/0/1/2/3/4/resources/4ra.html','',function(a){alert(a);});">
Get /home/user/0/1/2/3/4/resources/4ra.html</p>
<p onclick="$.get('/home/user/0/0a.html','',function(a){alert(a);});">
Get /home/user/0/0a.html</p>
<p onclick="$.get('/home/user/0/1/2/3/resources/3ra.html','',function(a){alert(a);});">
Get /home/user/0/1/2/3/resources/3ra.html</p>
</body></html>
```

System and browser:

```
Linux Road 2.6.32-23-generic-pae #37-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 11 09:26:55 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100628 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.6
```

The files are on the local file system. The url used is:

```
file:///home/user/0/1/2/3/4/test.html
```

The contents of each of the four files display as expected when the urls are entered into the web browser address bar by copying the urls directly from the displayed page (`/home/user/0/1/2/3/4/4a.html`, `/home/user/0/1/2/3/4/resources/4ra.html`, `/home/user/0/0a.html`, `/home/user/0/1/2/3/resources/3ra.html`).

But, accessing the file with http://localhost:8000/home/user/0/1/2/3/4/test.html, using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then all four work as expected.

Comment: I looked at your bio and just wanted to comment that I had the best pizza I've ever eaten in Julian, California.

Comment: @Alex JL: I don't understand, you haven't eaten at my house.:-)
Romono's, Poncho Villas (yes, tacos and pizza) or Wynola Pizza Express?

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea, since it was over 20 years ago and I was 6! But it must have been super good since I still remember. Just somewhere on the main strip in town. I'd swear it was like an old West saloon with swinging doors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` is preventing access. To correct enter `about:config` in the address bar, then change the value from `true` to `false` for `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` which will grant access to all of the files using scheme `file:` in addition to `http:`.

In long, starting point for this info came from Bartek's use of the the term [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and the Wikipedia link in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181911/why-does-jquery-get-home-user-0-0a-html-fail-when-using-file-rather-than-htt/3181932#3181932).

From [Browser Security Handbook, part 2](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2) - project hosting on Google Code:

> Firefox 3 is currently the only
>   browser that uses a directory-based
>   scoping scheme for same-origin access
>   within file://. This bears some risk
>   of breaking quirky local applications,
>   and may not offer protection for
>   shared download directories, but is a
>   sensible approach otherwise.

From Mozilla Developer Center [Same-origin policy for file: URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs):

> Starting in Gecko 1.9, files are
>   allowed to read only certain other
>   files.  Specifically, a file can read
>   another file only if the parent
>   directory of the originating file is
>   an ancestor directory of the target
>   file.

but,

> The new
>   security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy
>   preference, which defaults to true,
>   can be set to false if the user
>   doesn't want to strictly enforce the
>   same origin policy on file: URIs.

So, the second two files bumped into this restriction which can be addressed by changing the `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`.

Note that enabling access in other parts of the hierarchy does not grant any more access than is allowed by the file system directly.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but I have a feeling it's failing because `$.get()` follows the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) when processing a request and since /home/user/whatever is not a valid link and instead a filepath, it fails there.

I recommend taking the 2 minutes it takes to run a quick test server and try it with real URL's within your local domain.

If you have Python installed it's as simple as typing this in a terminal:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: I thought of same-domain restrictions too, and I've heard of people having problems with Ajax and file:/// vs. using an actual webserver. He does say that the first two work, though.

Comment: file:///home/user/0/0a.html produces the same result.

Comment: That's not what I told you to do?

Comment: The two that work are at the same level or lower in the file tree while the failures require access higher than the starting directory.

Comment: I too strongly suggest installing (or using, one might already be installed on Ubuntu) a webserver, perhaps Apache. Developing on a webserver is a much better plan than files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by closing your `<p>` tags, and seeing how it works then.

Also, you really should be binding events with `$().bind('click', function(){})` or `$().click(function(){})` rather than `onclick`.

Are you using Firebug, or looking at the error console?

I get a `mismatched tag. Expected: </p>.` error after clicking the first one. However, they all work for me.

Make sure that the files exist and the path is correct.

Here is a version with more jQuery like binding:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:////var/duck/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#p_1').click(function(){
          $.get('/home/user/whatever.html','',function(a{alert(a);});
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <p id='p_1'>
        Get /home/user/0/1/2/3/4/4a.html
      </p>
      <p id='p_2'>
        Get /home/user/0/1/2/3/4/resources/4ra.html
      </p>
      <p id='p_3'>
        Get /home/user/0/0a.html
      </p>
      <p id='p_4'>
        Get /home/user/0/1/2/3/resources/3ra.html
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Fill in the binds for each `<p>`. There are tons of ways you could link the elements to the preferred files, actually - delegation, arrays, indexes, etc.

Comment: Closing <p> tags produced no change.

Comment: You know that not closing them is making each section part of the previous <p> elements, right? Or it would, but Firefox is fixing your HTML for you. You must close your <p> tags. This HTML is invalid. It would probably blow up worse in IE.

Comment: Weird, I closed them and now get `mismatched tag. Expected: </BODY>.`. Oh.. apparently FF is being case sensitive on the tags.

Comment: Regardless, I'd suggest working with binding events in jQuery in this style rather than onclick, which is kind of archaic. Be sure to include the `$(document).ready()`. It worked for me, so I'm thinking it just can't locate the file you're requesting.